# Request for help with a quadratic polynomial question.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If the rooots of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ are real , show that the roots of the equation $x^2 +bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)$ are again real for every real number a.

---

I assumed the discriminant of the first eqution to be $\geq 0$ and found a relation between the coefficients. I wrote down the discriminant of the second equation and using the relation from the first equation , I tried to show that this discriminant also must be $\geq 0$, but I landed up with complicated calculations .
Since the two equation look similar to  each other , I believe there is a smarter way of doing this problem.

Comment: Did you try expanding those factors and rewriting? See if after expanding that last term, you can rewrite in such a way so that you can check the discriminant easily.

Comment: @Deepak it's not, I think you forgot to include the $x^2$ term

Comment: Yes, you're right, silly algebra mistake. Hadn't forgotten the $x^2$ term, just forgot how to square! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false when $a=2$, $b=4$, $c=-1$.

Comment: Thank you. I found the questio  in the book named Challenge and Thrill of Pre College Mathematics by C.R. Praneshachar and three others.I would like to know of there is a solution to the problem, for other numbers apart from the the one you have pointed out.

Comment: If you expand and simplify the discriminant of the second quadratic you get something like$$(b-2a)^2c^2+b^2(1+2c)$$- please check this as I don't have my working in front of me right now.  This will be negative if, for example, $b=2a$ and $c<-1/2$.